# How to avoid the duplicate if statement like this in PHP?

Tags: php

After organising  the follow PHP code, I found that they are actually repeat again and agian.

Is there any way to improve and extend the code into infinite level?

What do we generally call this problem in Technical Terms?

```
$tags = [
    0 => ['0.1','0.2'],
    1 => ['1.1','1.2'],
    2 => ['2.1','2.2']
];
$num = count($tags);
$level = 0;

foreach ($tags[$level] as $tag) {

    echo '<p style="text-indent:'.(2*$level).'em">';
    echo $tag;
    echo '</p>';

    $level++;
    if($level<=($num-1)){
        foreach ($tags[$level] as $tag) {
            echo '<p style="text-indent:'.(2*$level).'em">';
            echo $tag;
            echo '</p>';

                $level++ ;
                if($level<=($num-1)){
                    foreach ($tags[$level] as $tag) {
                        echo '<p style="text-indent:'.(2*$level).'em">';
                        echo $tag;
                        echo '</p>';

                        $level++ ;
                        if($level<=($num-1)){
                            foreach ($tags[$level] as $tag) {
                            echo '<p style="text-indent:'.(2*$level).'em">';
                            echo $tag;
                            echo '</p>'; 
                            }
                        } 
                        $level--;
                    }
                } 
                $level--;             
        }
    } 
    $level--;
}
```

This is the result of the code.

0.1

1.1

2.1

2.2

1.2

2.1

2.2

1.1

1.1

2.1

2.2

1.2

2.1

2.2

Comment: You are looking for recursion.

Comment: You can use recursion to solve this problem and that's also the term you're looking for

Comment: @jeroen, thank you so much. I'm now looking at the manual and trying to fix this problem.

Comment: @dimlucas, thank you so much. I'm now looking at the manual and trying to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$tags = Array(
    0 => Array('0.1','0.2'),
    1 => Array('1.1','1.2'),
    2 => Array('2.1','2.2'),
);
$num = count($tags);
myshow(0);

function myshow($level)
{
    global $tags, $num;

    foreach ($tags[$level] as $tag) {
        echo '<p style="text-indent:'.(2*$level).'em">';
        echo $tag;
        echo '</p>';

        if($level+1 < $num)
            myshow($level+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It's better than mine:)